# Can't toggle start()/stop() for ToneJS oscillators

Tags: javascript, tone.js

I have some JS cobbled together with the ToneJS library to toggle some sounds on/off.

```
function togglePlay() {
  const status = Tone.Transport.state; // Is either 'started', 'stopped' or 'paused'
  const element = document.getElementById("play-stop-toggle");
  if (status == "started") {
    element.innerText = "PLAY";
    Tone.Transport.stop()
  } else {
    element.innerText = "STOP";
    Tone.Transport.start()
  }

  document.querySelector('#status').textContent = status;
}


var filter = new Tone.Filter({
  type: 'lowpass',
  Q: 12
}).toMaster()



var fmOsc   = new Tone.AMOscillator("Ab3", "sine", "square").toMaster()
var fmOsc2  = new Tone.AMOscillator("Cb3", "sine", "square").toMaster()
var fmOsc3  = new Tone.AMOscillator("Eb3", "sine", "square").toMaster()

var synth   = new Tone.MembraneSynth().toMaster()

//create a loop
var loop = new Tone.Loop(function(time){
//    synth.triggerAttackRelease("A1", "8n", time)
//    fmOsc.start()
    fmOsc2.start()
    fmOsc3.start();
}, "4n")


//play the loop between 0-2m on the transport
loop.start(0)
// loop.start(0).stop('2m')
```

Inside the `loop` I have a drum beat that I have commented out currently.  When it was commented in, the `togglePlay()` function would start and stop it as expected.

However, the `fmOsc2` and `fmOsc3` functions will start when I toggle start, but do not terminate when I toggle stop.

For reference, here is what the HTML side looks like: `<div class="trackPlay" id="play-stop-toggle" onclick="togglePlay()">PLAY</div>`

How can I get the `fmOsc2` and `fmOsc3` functions to toggle with the button state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tone [Transport](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/Transport) is not meant to be used in this way, either for starting or stopping oscillators (it can start/stop oscillators, of course, but I don't think that it's doing what you want it to do) :-)

If you add a `console.log` within the function that you're passing to `Tone.Loop`, you will see that it's being called repeatedly i.e., you're calling `fmOsc.start()` over and over again. (It does make sense to do the repeating drum beat in that `Loop` though)

Calling `Tone.Transport.stop()` does not stop the oscillators -- it only stops the `Loop` / Transport function (i.e., the "time keeping"). The drum beat makes it obvious -- pressing `Stop` in your UI kills the drums, but the oscillators keep oscillating.

The easiest / most direct (and only?) way of stopping the oscillators is to call `.stop()` on them:

```
  if (status == "started") {
    element.innerText = "PLAY";
    Tone.Transport.stop()
    fmOsc2.stop()
    fmOsc3.stop()
  } else {
    // ... [snip] ...
```